# Параметрическое нахождение ближайшей точки в заданном направлении

Tags: алгоритм, php, mysql

Есть массив точек со случайными координатами.
Выбираем любую из них.
Задача: найти ближайшую к ней точку в заданном направлении.
Например, если речь идет о плоской карте, и надо найти ближайшую точку на востоке, мы фильтруем угол между северовостоком и юговостоком и ищем точку в нем, тупо сравнивая расстояния. Для трехмерного пространства все еще хуже. Особенно, если попытаться ввести систему ранжирования: если есть две точки, одна из них точно на восток, но на X дальше, а другая - на восток-северовосток под углом a, но чуть ближе, то будет выбрана та, для которой соблюдается определенное отношение X и a.

Вопрос:

1. как поступают умные люди в данной ситуации?
2. это задача для базы(MYSQL) или PHP?

Код писать не надо: как-нибудь справлюсь. Нужен алгоритм или волшебный пендель.

Comment: Интересная задача, на днях о подобном задумывался, интересно ответы услышать.

Comment: > это задача для базы(MYSQL) или PHP?

MySql - это БД
<br/>
PHP - серверный язык.
<br/>
У тебя следующий вопрос будет на чем лучше писать? Ну просто задача интересная, но вот читаю и понимаю что есть тут что-то скрытое :)

Comment: Я знаю, что такое mysql. ;)   
А вопрос "на чем лучше писать" я уже задал. Просто дело в том, что в постгресе подобные вопросы решаются на уровне БД, на сколько мне известно. По крайней мере, со специальным координатным модулем.   
Никто не делает `select *`, чтобы потов в PHP разгребать результат целой таблицы(хотя иногда это бывает необходимо, если идет сложный анализ строк). Ну и так далее.

Comment: есть тут что-то скрытое// Конечно есть. Изначальная задача вовсе не о позиционировании точек. Но к позиционированию точек все легко приводится.

Comment: > в постгресе подобные вопросы решаются на уровне БД, на сколько мне известно.

В Oracle вообще такая философия: все, что можно сделать запросом - лучше сделать запросом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL:

```
select TOP 1 id
from
  (
    select
      id,
      my_range_fn( dir_x, dir_y, dir_z, x0, y0, z0, x, y, z ) as range
    from Points p
  )
where range < 0
order by range desc
```

Пример ранжирующей функции ( JS ):

```
//2D карта на JS
//Север - 2, Запад - 4, Юг - 6, Восток - 0
//Рассматриваем попадание в угол в +- 45 градусов от направления
function my_range_fn( dir, x0, y0, x, y ){
  var dy = y - y0,
      dx = x - x0,
      rast = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy ),
      my_dir = Math.PI * ( ( dy > 0 ) ? 1 : 0 ) - Math.acos( dx / rast ),
      my_dir = ( my_dir < 0 ) ? Math.PI * 2 + my_dir : my_dir,
      dir = Math.PI * dir / 4;
      delta = Math.abs( my_dir - dir );

  return ( ( delta < Math.PI/4 ) ? -1 : 1 ) * rast - 2 *delta;
}
```

Используется коэф. 2 на разность желаемого направления и полученного
Примерно означает что при `(x0, y0) = (0, 0)` и направлении Сервер, выберет `(0,5)` вместо `(2,4)`

Comment: Воооть, уже ближе.
Идея нравится. Но не тяжеловата ли? Так же можно искать угол между векторами и длину векторов. Но мне кажется, что нагрузка окажется запредельной.

Comment: Можно кешировать отношения расстояний и углов между точками в подчиненную таблицу. Но, тогда, если точек много, то таких записей будет много в квадрате. Зато, при выборке данных, никаких промежуточных расчетов.

Comment: Тут не так много операций, что-бы нагрузка была большой...

Comment: Да, операций немного, но они сами по себе довольно непростые. А их придется применить много раз, так как точек может быть как много, так и очень много.

Comment: Но кол-во операций - константа, поэтому общая сложность вычисления - X*N...
На ту-же сортировку скорее всего больше времени понадобиться)<br>
P.S. - мы-же ище ближайшую к конкретной точке, любые ближайшие

Comment: Разве что попробовать логически упростить алгоритм ранжирования. К примеру для сравнения длин векторов корень можно и не извлекать, можно сравнивать квадраты.

Comment: @Kite, да, от sqrt и acos можно спойкойно отказаться

Answer (score 0):

Можно и с помощью MySQL. Если рассматривать вариант плоской сетки координат с точкой отсчета в центре, то северо-восток - это верхний правый квадрат. То-есть ограничения в запросе по х > 0 и у < 0 с учетом точки отсчета. Расчет расстояния по теореме Пифагора. Убывающая сортировка по расстоянию. Лимит 1 на вывод. На выходе ближайшая точка в заданном квадрате.

Comment: Угу. Это как раз то, что предложил я. Проблема в том, что тут никак не учитывается, что чем ближе точка к биссектрисе, тем они приоритетнее. Придется делать две сортировки. Причем не самых элементарных. Так как точки будут выбираться часто, это серьезно загрузит систему. Неужели нет более оптимизированных решений?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала выберем систему координат с центром в первой точке
Особенность задачи - в наличии ограничений на угол `(|fi|<45)`, что наталкивает на мысли о полярной системе координат и уравнениях вида `r=R(cos(fi)-cos(pi/4))`.

При этом в качестве критерия оптимальности напрашивается параметр уравнения
`R = r/(cos(fi)-sqrt(2)/2) = r^2/(x-r*sqrt(2)/2)`
с размерностью расстояния. И тогда останется главное - правильно учесть ограничения.